# Index (columns [0]) have duplicate values

Tags: pandas

I have the following data:

```
Start Time=2012-04-12   16:13:09    
Finish Time=2012-11-30  13:31:08    
Sample Period=01:00:00
```

As a CSV file:

```
Date(yyyy-mm-dd)    Time(hh:mm:ss)  Celsius (C)
2012-04-12          16:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          17:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          18:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          19:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          20:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          21:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          22:13:09        20.6
2012-04-12          23:13:09        20.6
```

and now I want to read-in data by pandas like this:

```
df=read_csv('mmf0401.txt',skiprows=(0,5),parse_dates=[[0,1]],index_col=0)
```

Unfortunately, it raises an exception `Index (columns [0]) have duplicate values ['2012-04-12']`

I don't know why, how can I correct this?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? This seems to work fine (without error) for me using `0.9.0`...

Comment: Thank you very much,It's the version problem.I use 0.7.3,but when I upgrade pandas to 0.9.0,it becomes ok. And thank you for editing:)